# Stop loading a new route/component if current component has changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a requirement where I need to check if the local state has changes before the user navigates to the next tab. sort of like handing a component abandonment. I have come up with 2 options as follows,

1. Achieve this via `componentWillUnmount`. If its a good practice is there a way to conditionally stop the component being unmounted?
2. Via the `window`. As stated in the following solution : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/z63RGG1l_0U

Any idea on this matter is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There is no way to stop the unmounting of a component via `componentWillUnmount` - this lifecycle function is called only when the comonponent **WILL** unmount :)

Answer (score 1):

In the [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) router is part of the state, so you can experiment on that.

To do so you should take a look at [RouterContext](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#routercontext), which provides setRouteLeaveHook function.
OR
As far as I remember there's also second option. Router object on context contains **listenBeforeLeavingRoute**

```
this.context.router.listenBeforeLeavingRoute
```

But its basically the same thing if you look at the source code of react-router. But its accessible from different layers.

EDIT:also [Route](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route) has onLeave hook, may be useful!

Hope it helps somehow.

Regards,
  Mariusz

Comment: Thanks for the answer.i ll check this and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

How does the user navigate to the next tab? When you are using a `<Link>` you could define an `unsavedChanges` flag in your state. Set this to true (via dispatching an action and having a reducer responsible for that action) whenever you think that the user must not leave the current tab.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    const { unsavedChanges } = this.props
    if(unsavedChanges) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Link to='/nextTab' onClick={this.handleClick}>Bar</Link>
    )
  }
}
```

Of course you need to pass `unsavedChanges` to your components props.